# Deming Regression - Error Bars

Tags: r

I am using the "mcr" package for weighted Deming regression of two variables.  I am trying to add error bars to each point (horizontal and vertical.  I was wondering if there is a function within the program or a program that can used in conjunction with the mcr package in order to visualize the SE for both x and y.  I have found a temporary solution using arrows as shown below; however I do not believe its the best way to show my data.

So far, i have found that ggplot2 doesnt work with mcr and se.lines doesnt seem to be working either.  Any input would be appreciated.

Furthermore, if anyone could explain where I might find the Standard Error values for the X value, I would appreciate it.

Thank you everyone for their time.

## exampledata

```
xo<-     c(18.05,15.78,23.44,15.93,25.71,16.06,21.36,18.11,14.78,11.74,17.56,17.04,14.20,10.68,17.96)
yo<-c(3.07,2.32,2.63,2.50,3.02,2.24,3.13,2.46,2.23,2.31,2.55,2.69,2.32,1.77,2.97)
```

## using mcr

```
 library(mcr)
 w.dem.reg.o<-mcreg(xo,yo,method.reg="WDeming",method.ci="jackknife")
 w.dem.reg.o@para #getting info on the line
MCResult.plot(w.dem.reg.o,x.lab="parameter1",y.lab="parameter2",sub="",main="Parameter 1 vs Parameter 2: Deming Regression",points.col="gold",points.cex =1,points.pch=19,ci.area = TRUE,reg=TRUE,identity=TRUE,ci.border=TRUE,add.legend = FALSE)

legend(x="topleft",c("Y = 1.07 + 0.09X", "SE of Intercept = 0.4724","SE of     Slope = 0.0276")) #aesthetic.only 

arrows(xo,yo+0.15692,
xo,yo-0.15692,length=0,angle=90,code=3,col="purple")
arrows(xo+0.4724,yo,
xo-0.4724,yo,length=0,angle=90,code=3,col="purple")
points(xo,yo)
```

## temporary solution found.  I am aware that the SE values are incorrect.  I will be adding individual SE values when the time comes.